# How can I optimize multiple if-else statements with a switch statement?

Tags: php-7, optimization, coding-style

I am writing code to add review emails to the queue based on the channels like Amazon, Walmart and so on. The way I am doing it is as follows. I would like to know if the code can be optimized in some other way such as using a Switch or something so that I don't have to use multiple if-else statments.

```
    if ($my_order->pay_method == AMAZONSTORE) {
        $emailQueue = new Luxe_EmailQueue();
        // $emailQueue->replace_or_add(EMAIL_REVIEW_MAIL1, $customerData->email, $subject, $body, $send_date_php, $my_order->id);
        // Temporary adding bcc
        $emailQueue->replace_or_add(EMAIL_REVIEW_MAIL1, $customerData->email, $subject, $body, $send_date_php, $my_order->id, null, "", "berkell990@gmail.com");
        $emailQueue->save();
        unset($emailQueue);

        // Add second (reminder) email also, for 7 days after the first email.
        $emailQueue = new Luxe_EmailQueue();
        // $emailQueue->replace_or_add(EMAIL_REVIEW_MAIL2, $customerData->email, $subject,
        // $smarty->fetch('amazon_store_review_email2.tpl'), $email_dispatch_dates['second_review_email_date_php'], $my_order->id);
        // Temporary adding bcc
        $emailQueue->replace_or_add(EMAIL_REVIEW_MAIL2, $customerData->email, $subject,
            $smarty->fetch('amazon_store_review_email2.tpl'), $email_dispatch_dates['second_review_email_date_php'], $my_order->id, null, "", "berkell990@gmail.com");
        $emailQueue->save();
        unset($emailQueue);
    } elseif ($my_order->pay_method == PMM) {
        # code...
    } elseif ($my_order->pay_method == RP) {
        # code...
    } elseif ($my_order->pay_method == WALMART) {
        # code...
    } elseif ($my_order->pay_method == EBAY) {
        # code...
    } else {
        // NO payment Method matched.
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Try This way

```
switch ($my_order->pay_method) {
  case "AMAZONSTORE":
    # code...
    break;
  case "PMM":
    # code...
    break;
  case "RP":
    # code...
    break;
  case "WALMART":
    # code...
    break;
  case "WALMART":
    # code...
    break;
  default:
    // NO payment Method matched.
}
```